# XSLT 3.0: Using a accumulator , how to accumulator values and break a line between them And how to reset the accumulator

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have xml (described below) with footnotes (described 'note' tag ), which I want to turn into a -html document divided into pages, where up to the 'eop' tag accumulate 'note' tags  in the  accumulator 'notes' and then pull out all the 'note' tags that have accumulated so far and display them and close the page.
Go to the next page and so on.
Each individual footnote should be in a separate line,
To do this you have to wrap each individual footnote in the div tag (which I could not do) or alternatively move to the next line before each new footnote (what you see in xslt below but does not work)

And another thing I need is to reset the occulator as soon as there is an eop.
I added (<xsl: accumulator-rule match = "eop" select = "''" />) but it over before showing
The following xslt describes what I did and does not do what is required
Can someone help me?

xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataRoot>
    <article>
        <point>
            <p>aaa</p>
            <note marker="*" >note 1</note>
            <p>bbb
                <eop>100</eop>
            </p>
            <p>ccc
                <note marker="*">note 2</note>
            </p>
        </point>
        <point>
            <note marker="**">note 3</note>
            <p>ddd</p>
            <p>eee</p>
        </point>
        <point>
            <note marker="***">note 4</note>
        </point>
        <eop>101</eop>
    </article>
    <article>
        <note marker="*">note 5</note>
        <point>
            <p>fff</p>
            <p>ggg
                <eop>102</eop>
            </p>
        </point>
        <point>
            <note marker="*">note 6</note>
        </point>
    </article>
</dataRoot>
```

xslt:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0" >
    <xsl:mode use-accumulators="#all" streamable="no"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:accumulator name="notes" initial-value="''">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="note" select="concat($value,'&#10;',@marker,.)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                 
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="eop">
        <div class="line">
            -- </div>
        <div class="note">
            <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('notes')"/>
        </div>
        <div class="eop">
            <xsl:value-of select='.' />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            ------------ </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="article" >
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="point" >
        <div class="point">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p" >
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="note" >
        <span class="authorialNote">
            <xsl:value-of select="@marker"/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output html:

```html
aaa * bbb
--
*note 1
100
------------
ccc *
** ddd eee
***
--
*note 1 *note 2 **note 3 ***note 4
101
------------
*
fff ggg
--
*note 1 *note 2 **note 3 ***note 4 *note 5
102
------------
*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I do understand

> And another thing I need is to reset the occulator as soon as there is
> an eop. I added (`<xsl:accumulator-rule match = "eop" select = "''" />`) but it over before showing

if you want to reset when encountering an `eop` that code should be right; as you, however, try to read out the value when matching on `eop` I supposed you rather want to reset with `<xsl:accumulator-rule match = "eop" select = "''" phase="end"/>`.

As for inserting line break, perhaps don't collect a single string value as the accumulator value but a sequence of strings e.g.

```
<xsl:accumulator name="notes" as="xs:string*" initial-value="()">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="note" select="$value, @marker || ."/>
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="eop" select="()" phase="end"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

then, `accumulator-before('notes')` gives you a sequence of string you can process with `xsl:iterate` or `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates` to wrap in adequate markup (e.g. `div` or `ul`/`li` or with `br`) inserted.